# How SDK platforms work in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-3.0

I am confused about how SDK platforms work in android studio.

I have only a few SDK platforms installed, yet i am able to run my app for MeMu android 4.4.4 emulator.

When creating the project i set min version to android 4, i assume that's why it can run on android 4+. but then what are these SDK platforms and what will be missed if i dont have them installed?

[image]

Comment: Check the box where it says "Show Package Details" you will see what are those for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are different versions of the SDK released for the different versions of the platform.  Generally you just install the latest and use that for a new project.  However not all projects jump right on updating it, so if you're working on a pre-existing app you may need to download whatever version they were using at the time.

Comment: so they are backwards compatible? i thought i have to install all of those SDK's! so if an old project was written with old sdk that's the only time i have to get older sdk's.

Comment: Back and forward compatible.  You can compile an app with SDK 26 and it will work on an OS with SDK 20 or 30.  You just won't be able to access new additions in later SDKs, and you may crash if you try to access features that were added in sdk 26 on a phone that's sdk 20.  Features like that should have a version check and only be used if the version is high enough.